# iPhone 5 will not ring, it only vibrates

Tags: iphone

I have my iPhone 5 set on "Vibrate on Ring" and the volume is not on mute, but when someone calls, it only vibrates. I've included it in Notifications Center, but that doesn't seem to do anything. Do Not Disturb has also been turned off. When selecting a ringtone it will not play, it only vibrates. How do I fix this?

Comment: Might seem obvious, but - did you check the mute switch on the side?

Comment: yes I did, but still only vibrates

Comment: Does the phone play any sound at all?

Comment: no it only vibrates

Comment: Does iTunes, or any other sound, work? Starting to sound like your headphone socket needs some tlc.

Comment: no sounds work at all :(   so what r u suggesting?

Comment: just plugged headphones in and I get music via Pandora

Comment: how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I can hear it ringing if I have headphones in :(   gosh what do u suggest to fix it?

Comment: Now try removing the headphones. This may trigger the switch.

Comment: nup it didn't - bugger!

Comment: Go To Settings > Sounds > Try a ringtone from the list to see if that works. At the top of that list is Vibrate On Ring and Vibrate On Silent. Turn them both off. I assume that you have checked the mute switch is off on the side of your phone. Also, I'm assuming that you might have tried to change the volume: Select a ringtone to try and when it's going, use the up and  down keys to change volume. Check all those and update us..

Answer (score 2):

Get some compressed air (don't just blow into it) and blow the headphone jack clean of any dirt, lint, or other debris. A toothpick might help clean it out, too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds (no pun intended) like a software issue.

Try this:

### Hard reset

- Hold down the **home** and **reset** buttons simultaneously until you see the  logo.
- let go of both buttons together

The phone will restart. This may fix your issue. I had a similar problem recently. A reset did the trick.

If this doesn't work, a trip to the Genius Bar at your *local* Apple Store may be your last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching ringtones. I did that and then switched back to my original (custom) ringtone and it worked again.